# Rails i18n in one table (CakePHP-like)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp, internationalization

Is there a Gem that stores translations in one table like CakePHP does?

The polymorphic CakePHP i18n-table has the following structure:

```
id
locale
model
foreign_key
field
content
```

Globalize3 i.e. uses a new table for each model translation which I find too redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add various backends to the i18n gem which generally provides internationalization for ruby. Globalize3 is one option. A more lightweight alternative could be [i18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record) which uses a single table similar to your CakePHP example.